# How do you test that a method that uses reflection to invoke a method on different classes, invokes the correct class

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq, xunit

I have a service, which calls an Invoke method on different classes, based on a class attribute found via reflection. I am wanting to test that the correct class is instantiated and the method called.

Service:

```
private void InvokeCorrectClass(string message)
{
    //find type from cache of types based on info in message
    //_cacheTypes is Dictionary<Type, string>
    var type = _cacheTypes.First(p=>p.Value == msg.MessageType).Key;
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    var invokeMethod = type.GetMethod("Invoke");

    invokeMethod.Invoke(instance, new object[] {msg, messageId});
}
```

Of course, I'm leaving out some null checking and error handling....

Class 1:

```
public async Task Invoke(object message, int messageId)
{
    //process MessageType 1
}
```

Class 2:

```
public async Task Invoke(object message, int messageId)
{
    //process MessageType 2
}
```

I know the code is working correctly, as I hit the correct code using breakpoints, but I'm trying to use Moq and XUnit to automate that the correct class is created and called, and am having no luck at all.

Also, neither Class 1 or Class 2 have parameter-less constructors, and a lot of dependencies. I've tried adding a parameter-less constructor so I can Mock it out with the setup:

```
_testModule.MessageProcessorMock.Setup(i => i.Invoke(It.IsAny<object>, It.IsAny<int>()))
                .Returns<object, int>((msg, messageId) =>
                {
                    msgId = messageId;
                    msgPassedOn = msg;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                });
```

but it is never called.

Comment: Instead of mocking and checking that certain methods are called, test that expected behaviour is executed. What method invoked by using reflection does? Test that.

Comment: I'm trying to do more of a unit test, vs an integration test, and mocking out the response of the called method would allow me to return without having to do all of the setup of all of the dependencies.

Comment: Do not concentrate on the terms (unit or integration), all tests are just tests, which provide feedback on production code. mock only slow(external resources) and very very complicated dependencies. Less mocks in the test more valuable test is.

Comment: Another approach: struggling when writing tests can be a sign that current approach isn't "testable/mockable". You can change a code to make it more "unit" testable(interfaces everywhere) or you can mock less and use "integration" tests to cover "difficult" logic.

Comment: Another approach: if you can change a code and pass cached types as a dependency of class under the test. Then in tests you can pass own cached types, which will be easy to assert that correct class was invoked.